# PHP attributes with Vim

Tags: php, vim

I am using Vim to code in PHP, and I have seen that the [attributes syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.syntax.php) (`#[...]`) is parsed as a comment in the vim syntax highlighting.

I would like to make sure that `#[` is not treated as a comment while `#` followed by any character other than `[` stays a comment.

I never messed with the syntax configuration of vim before so I am not versed in how it works but I have tried to add a `after/syntax/php.vim` file where I redefine the `phpComment` group as follows, and the default match remains active in addition to the one I defined. I don't know how to override them.

```
if exists("php_parent_error_open")
    syn region phpComment start="/\*" end="\*/" fold contained contains=phpTodo,@Spell
else
    syn region phpComment start="/\*" end="\*/" fold contained contains=phpTodo,@Spell extend
endif
syn match phpComment "#[^\[].\{-}\(?>\|$\)\@=" contained contains=phpTodo,@Spell
syn match phpComment "//.\{-}\(?>\|$\)\@=" contained contains=phpTodo,@Spell
```

I have also tried to use `call matchdelete('phpComment', "#\[*$")` but I got an error saying I had an invalid id and that id should be greater or equal to 1 (I am pretty sure I did not understand how to use the `matchdelete` function but I am not sure it is the easiest way to fix this issue).

I have also considered creating a new syntax highlighting for everything contained between `#[` and `]` to override the comment highlighting but I don't know the syntax system of vim enough and it seems like a lot of work to learn it all for so few.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Vim and syntax file are you using?  
Because I've just checked and (at least in 8.2-2891 with syntax file from 2020-12-22) the attributes are not treated as comments

Comment: Vim version 8.2 (2019-12-12) and the syntax file is from 2020-12-22. I just tried changing the match rule directly in the $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim file but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem: I had the plugin vim-polyglot installed, whith an other php.vim syntax file which took priority over the $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim file - and is not up to date with PHP8 features.